# Matplotlib plot frame

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider this plot:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    a = np.arange(0,3, .02)
    b = np.arange(0,3, .02)
    c = np.exp(a)

    # Create plots with pre-defined labels.
    # Alternatively, you can pass labels explicitly when calling `legend`.
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(a, b, 'k', label='Model length')
    ax.plot(a, c, 'k:', label='Data length')

    # Now add the legend with some customizations.
    legend = ax.legend(loc='upper center', shadow=True)

    # The frame is matplotlib.patches.Rectangle instance surrounding the 
    # legend.
    frame = legend.get_frame()
    frame.set_facecolor('0.90')

    plt.show()
```

This plot as well as many others I have tried, should have a frame (4 spines).
For me it only shows the axis but no spines. How can I change that?

[image]

Edit:

The problem here was the seaborn library. If this library is imported at any point it will change the format of matplotlib plots and they will look like the plot shown above. (Nicer design but no spines;)

Comment: For debugging purposes, try some of the default style-sheets available [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html) which will overwrite a lot of possibly broken settings. If those work, you have to check, why the internals are by default not plotting those spines. (working inside ipython/jupyter?; some stuff unknown in one of matplotlib's config files (maybe called matplotlib.rc)?)

Comment: If you ask a question with a code that is not a [mcve], you're wasting everyone's time (including your own).

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from being an expert but I solved the same problem by changing the color of the spines

```
for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set_color('black')
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code as it is should display with the spines
[image]
However, try adding the following lines to your code.

```
for spine in ax.spines.values():
        spine.set_visible(True)
```

Answer (score -3):

You need just to add numpy as np in your code

```
import numpy as np
```

Please see the third code in https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

And what i got is :
[image]

Comment: I already did that, just did not display it. Any graph I produce is without a frame, this is so weird. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Even if you try this code did not display it ?

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()

Comment: Found the mistake, at some point I imported seaborn which changes the format of the matplotlib plots, that's why my design also looked a little different.

Comment: i'm happy to hear that you found the cause. Good luck.

Comment: @Julia if you figured it out, please edit your question (by adding how did you fix it)

Comment: @kingmakerking No, questions should not contain the answer! (A question is a question.) Of course the questioner can answer their own question if they want.

Comment: Ah. Sorry, I meant add the answer (not to the question) with a comment in the question saying I found the answer.